# I have a 2006 Ford Explorer that seems to bog down

Tags: ford, brakes, explorer

I changed the brakes line brake cylinder brakes caliber and the car still boggs down. what do you think is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "bogs down"? Usually this indicates an acceleration issue, not a braking issue? Also, which engine does your explorer have? What transmission? Is it 4wd or just 2wd?

Comment: Along with defining what "bogs down" is, what do _you_ think is wrong with the car?  Often times someones description of what they think is wrong is a good way to get details that you might not think to add otherwise.

Comment: Can you add additional information to the question?  What does bog down mean?  What engine you have.  4wd or 2wd.  What are your thoughts on the issue and why?  Thanks!

Comment: Voting to close, OP is not responding to comments asking for more information/clarification.